# Give a user only permission to /var/www/dir/

Tags: linux, apache, debian

I'm updating my setup on my Raspberry Pi to make it possible to host sites for friends. But I'm having a problem with permissions. Let's start with the point I am not an expert at user management on Linux.

Anyways, I've added a user using the **adduser** command. But now I want to give that user only access to the directory */var/www/user* so they only can use that directory via FTP. How can I do that?

Kind regards,

Martin.

Comment: You may jail them, meaning they cannot move to another dir above their home dir. In http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/howto-linux-unix-rssh-chroot-jail-setup.html you can see a good explanation how to do it.

Comment: @fedorqui Thanks for your answer, I will give that a try. So if I edit their home dir to /var/www/usrhome and jail them into that directory it should work. I'll give that a try!

Comment: Yes. Note you have to configure some SSH stuff. Make backup of all the files you touch and give it a try, it should work!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@fedorqui answer(comment) Is great. But there is other way to achieve this. I don't see in your question that the user need an SSH connection. Some FTP software(server) like vsftpd allow to chroot/jail a user into a folder/home directly in their configuration. More over you may deny the user to connect via ssh directly in OpenSsh configuration

here some link that might help with the configuration if you choose vsftpd [Chroot/jail a user](http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/vsftp-chroot-users-limit-to-only-their-home-directory.html), 
[Deny direct ssh connection with openssh](http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/openssh-deny-or-restrict-access-to-users-and-groups.html)
, Hope it helped

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I'm using ProFTPD and I discovered it is very easy to accomplish that. Just adding one line to a configuration file. Thanks for you help.

Comment: No problem, also if you could either accept my answer or add another answer yourself and accept it so this question get tag as resolve. Have a nice day